# why i am not able to install cdh3

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/CDH3+Installation#CDH3Installation-InstallingCDH3onUbuntuSystems

I have ubuntu 8.04 ,i wget the squeeze and tried to dpkg it gives me this error .

```
ksn@ksn-test:~$ sudo dpkg -i cdh3-repository_1.0_all.deb
(Reading database ... 59905 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace cdh3-repository 1.0 (using cdh3-repository_1.0_all.deb) ...
rm: cannot remove `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cloudera-cdh3.gpg': No such file or directory
dpkg: warning - old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg - trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg: ... it looks like that went OK.
Unpacking replacement cdh3-repository ...
Setting up cdh3-repository (1.0) ...
gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cloudera-cdh3.gpg': file open error
gpg: no writable keyring found: eof
gpg: error reading `/usr/share/doc/cdh3-repository/cloudera-cdh3.key': general error
gpg: import from `/usr/share/doc/cdh3-repository/cloudera-cdh3.key' failed: general error
gpg: Total number processed: 0
dpkg: error processing cdh3-repository (--install):
 subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cdh3-repository
```

why this error is coming

Comment: Looks like you had cdh3-repository package already installed?

Comment: Does the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` directory exist?